# SQL Server Identity Specification causing slowdown of database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, identity

I have a sql server 2005 database with an ms access frontend.

Our main projects table has primary key of the project number. I recently added identity specification to the project number, so my users wouldn't have to type a new PN each time.

The problem is that this has caused the table to really slow down when viewed in Access.

My question is why has changing

```
[P/N] [int] NOT NULL,
```

to

```
[P/N] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

caused slowness?

Is there anyway to keep my PNs autonumbering and maintain reasonable performance?

Comment: Since you can't just change an existing primary key on a table to identity, how did you achieve this?  Did you use the temp->identity->copy->drop pattern? Or drop the old pk and add a new one? Could that be the problem, that indexes on the new table are not working?

Also, is it really only when viewed in Access? Have you checked the access times in SqlServer itself - if your table is v. large for example then adding identity spec could have swollen your translog and that could be perhaps slowing things down in general (depending on what's going on when you load these records into Access, etc)

Comment: I used Management studio to change the identity so not sure how it was done. On a backup of the db I have changed it back and it is back to its usual speed in Access. My problem is just in Access, could it be due to the size, 50000 rows?

Comment: Could be - are you trying to read all of the rows into Access or just selecting one row at a time as needed?

Comment: all rows of the table are opened and then people use filters to find the data they need.

Comment: I wonder is it that Access had some kind of cache for the data, which is blown away now that the table schema has changed. Beyond that I can only suppose that perhaps Access doesn't like something about the new identity field.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an identity column is a small overhead and shouldn't cause much of a performance hit. Have you tried updating statistics after altering the column? Check your indexes on the table as well.